# Writing a function using (**kwargs) then summing

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I want to define a function. This function should be able to accept variable number of keyword arguments of not predefined names. Then the function returns the number of keyword arguments.

For example:

```
result = all_the_kwargs(my_kwarg = "random", second_kwarg = "more", some_number = 1)

print(result)  # should print the number 3
```

I don't understand how I can count the number of keyword arguments with heterogeneous values (integers and strings mixed).

Comment: What part of this task are you having trouble with? What specific question about this task do you want to ask us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def all_the_kwargs(**kwargs):
    return len(kwargs)
```

This will take all the arguments as a dictionary and return the length of it.

Comment: So simple! I was way overthinking it !! Thank you